# What does mean by the independent columns in 4NF normalization?

Tags: database-theory, databases

For a table to satisfy the Fourth Normal Form, it should satisfy the following two conditions:

It should be in the Boyce-Codd Normal Form.
And, the table should not have any Multi-valued Dependency.
The table should have at least 3 attributes and B and C should be independent for $A \twoheadrightarrow B$ multivalued dependency.

**Now,** I do not get the meaning of the following line "for a relation $R(A,B,C)$, ***if there is a multi-valued dependency between, A and B, then B and C should be independent of each other***."

What does mean by independent of each other? Does the word ***independent*** mean that there should not be any FD such as $B\rightarrow C$ , or $C\rightarrow B$, or $BC \rightarrow A$?

Please help me. I did not get any proper explanation of this line or I failed to understand the meaning of the line in different sources.